# show webcam stream from OpenCV with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opencv3.0

so i can see my webcam stream with OpenCV with imshow with this simple code

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); 
    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("webcam", 1);
    while (true)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; 
        imshow("webcam", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

now what i want to is to show the image from OpenCV in QImage in Widget on QT
Here is a conversion from cv::Mat to QImage

```
QImage Mat2QImage(cv::Mat const& src)
{
    cv::Mat temp; 
    cvtColor(src, temp, CV_BGR2RGB); 
    QImage dest((const uchar *)temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    dest.bits(); 
    // of QImage::QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
    return dest;
}
```

and the little code to show an image with QImage in QT

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QImage myImage;
    myImage.load("a.png");
    QLabel myLabel;
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
    myLabel.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

i tried to combine them in this way, but no luck

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    QImage myImage;
    QLabel myLabel;
    while (true)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

        myImage = Mat2QImage(frame);
        myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
    }


    myLabel.show();

    return a.exec();
```

Comment: This is not how it works. You enter in an infinite loop : how could you see anything, since the `myLabel.show()` is *after* the loop ?

Comment: Streaming from a device along with any processing of the image data should be done in a separate thread. If you do what you're doing sooner or later you will have to rewrite your code. Check a couple of videos I've made on integration of OpenCV with Qt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKIEzqmeajQ&index=1&list=PLxpCFVM0F4wWJm8LB-_-_U-ag6knR8Kmc&ab_channel=rbaleksandar Note that you can also use a custom `QThread` and you don't have to stick to the Worker pattern I've used in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a `Window` that inherits from `QMainWindow` with a `QTimer`. In the constructor, connect the timer to a `Window` method. You will put your openCV code into this timeout method, that will be called every X millisecond:

```
class Window : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTimer _timer;

    private slots:
    void on_timeout()
    {
        // put your opencv code in it
    }
    public:
    Window() :
        QMainWindow(), _timer(this)
    {
        connect(&_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_timeout()));
        // populate your window with images, labels, etc. here
        _timer.start(10 /*call the timer every 10 ms*/);
    }
};
```

Then show your Window in the main :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window win;
    win.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

If you use Qt creator, it is simpler to develop with Qt: think about it.